# How explode and regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, preg-match

I have this Link :

```
http://www.mySite.come/part1/one-two-12/one-two-three-four-x36-250g-P469198/
```

i want to chek if the last part starts with 'P' and numbers like : P432432

how can i explode and check my condition?

i tried:

```
url="http://www.mySite.come/part1/one-two-12/one-two-three-four-x36-250g-P469198/"
url.s.split('-')
```

Comment: `url.split('-')[-1]`..you will get the last part with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
re.sub("[^\w]", "" , url.split('-')[-1])
```

to get the last part and validate it using

```
re.match("P\d+", re.sub("[^\w]", "", url.split('-')[-1]))
```

or

```
re.search("P\d+", re.sub("[^\w]", "", url.split('-')[-1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-P\d+/?$` regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> url = "http://www.mySite.come/part1/one-two-12/one-two-three-four-x36-250g-P469198/"
>>> re.search(r"-P\d+/?$", url)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x104faf920>
```

Explanation:

- `-P` is a dash followed by `P`, literally
- `\d+` would match one or more digits
- `/?` would optionally match a slash (taking into account that it might not be always present)
- `$` would match the end of the string

If you want to extract that part, use a *capturing group*:

```
>>> match = re.search(r"-(P\d+)/?$", url)
>>> match.group(1)
'P469198'
```

Comment: No need escaping `-` outside the character class.

Comment: @alecxe you only corrected it in 1 of 3 places, but it is a nice solution.

Comment: @Remuze are you sure? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to check if the last part contains `-Pdigit`, you can use:

```
if re.search(r"-P\d+/$", subject, re.DOTALL):
    # Successful match
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```

---

```
-P\d+/$

Options: Case sensitive; Exact spacing; Dot matches line breaks; ^$ don’t match at line breaks; Regex syntax only

Match the character string “-P” literally (case sensitive) «-P»
Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «\d+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “/” literally «/»
Assert position at the end of the string, or before the line break at the end of the string, if any (line feed) «$»
```